# How to make IconButton bigger?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to make IconButton bigger, but this doesn't work.
How to make the size of the button bigger?

```
SizedBox(
height: 100,
width: 100,
child: IconButton(
  tooltip: 'Refresh',
  icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Check()),
    );
  },
),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the property `iconSize`.

Here is the official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton/iconSize.html).

**Solution:**

```
IconButton(
      iconSize: 100,
      tooltip: 'Refresh',
      icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      onPressed: () {
          //Your code goes here....
      }
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `iconSize` property...You dont need to use `SizedBox` when using `iconSize`

```
IconButton(
      iconSize: 100,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      onPressed: () {}
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iconSize property of IconButton() widget, it will help to increase the size. This property increases the size of icon inside it too. So, put the size of Icon() as well so that you can have the desired size of IconButton and Icon both.

```
IconButton(
iconSize: 100,
tooltip: 'Refresh',
icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh, size:20),
onPressed: () {
  
},)
```

Answer (score 0):

`IconButton` sets height and width internally, with nothing to do with any parent Widget.

```
IconButton(
      iconSize: 100,
```

internally, `IconButton` sets the height and width of the icon as 100, and default iconSize is  `this.iconSize = 24.0,`. That's important to make look icons good.